# C++ Templates for classes

Tags: c++, oop, templates

in this code I tried to make a template for my class, and also 2 template functions, one for standard types and one for my template class, but I wanted to see if I can make a template in a template to get a defined function (I don't know if this was the right way to make it). Finally, after I run the code it gives me some weird errors, like syntax errors etc. Thx for help!

```
  #include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Complex
{
    T _re, _im;

public:
    Complex(T re = 0, T im = 0) :_re{re}, _im{im} {};
    ~Complex() {}
    Complex<T>& operator=(const Complex<T>& compl) { if (this == &compl) return *this; this._re = compl._re; this._im = compl._im; return *this; }
    Complex<T> operator+(const Complex<T>& compl) { Complex<T> temp; temp._re = _re + compl._re; temp._im = _im + compl._im; return temp}
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Complex<T>& compl) { os << compl._re << " * i " << compl._im; return os; }
};

template <typename T>
T suma(T a, T b)
{
    return a + b;
}

template <template<typename> typename T, typename U>
void suma(T<U> a, T<U> b)
{
    T<U> temp;

    temp = a + b;

    std::cout << temp;
}

int main()
{
    int a1{ 1 }, b1{ 3 };
    std::cout << "Suma de int : " << suma<int>(a1, b1) << std::endl;

    double a2{ 2.1 }, b2{ 5.9 };
    std::cout << "Suma de double: " << suma<double>(a2, b2) << std::endl;

    Complex<int> c1(3, 5), c2(8, 9);
    std::cout << "Suma comple int: ";
    suma<Complex, int>(c1, c2);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`compl`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/compl) is a c++ keyword (as an alternative for unary operator `~`). You used `compl` as your operator overload parameters.

I didn't know this just a few minutes ago. How did I find out? I pasted your code into [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org) and it highlighted the words "compl" as if they were keywords. One Internet search later, they are indeed keywords.

There's also the use of `this._re = ...` and `this._im = ...` which doesn't work since `this` is a pointer and not a reference, so it should be `this->_re = ...` or preferably, just `_re = ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Your have 3 errors in your program.

**First** instead of using the keyword `compl` you could use some other name like i did [here](https://onlinegdb.com/Be8UyH7Ol).

**Second**, you were missing a `;` after a statement `return temp`  which is fixed in the above code link.

**Third** you were using

```
this._re = rhs._re;
this._im = rhs._im;
```

while the correct way to write this would be:

```
_re = rhs._re;//note the removed this.
_im = rhs._im;//note the removed this.
```

After correcting these errors the program works as can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/Be8UyH7Ol).